# Smarty gives Fatal error on editing .tpl file

Tags: php, html, smarty, fatal-error

I am facing a problem whenever I edit my `header-home.tpl` file (even space or comment line) it says

```
Fatal error: Smarty error: [in header-home.tpl.html line 114]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments) (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 415) in D:\xampplite\TFS-WorkSpace\EventCompany\lib\modules\Smarty\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 999
```

but when I edit any other file like `contact.tpl.html` it works fine.

I tried disabling `$smarty->compile_check = false;` but no success. Help me

**Header.tpl.html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Event Planning Agency, Event Manager Services, Corporate Event Management, Exhibition, Conference, Party Organiser in Dubai, UAE | The Event Company</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The-Event-Company.com offers Event Management, Conference Management, Sponsorship Activation, Promotional Events, Event Furniture/Prop Hire, Launch Events, Mall Events, Exhibition Stand Design, Exhibition Management, Catering Service, RSVP Management and Wedding Planning in Dubai. Call us at +971 4 304 2468 and we will plan a personalized agenda for your event today." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Event Planning, Event manager, Event Services, Corporate Events, Party Event Planning, Corporate Event Planning, Event Planning Services, Event Management Services, Corporate Event Management, Exhibition Management, The Event Company, Event Management Dubai, Dubai Event Management, Event Planning Service, Event Management Agency, Corporate Event Services, Event Company Dubai, Event Company Dubai, UAE event management, Furniture Hire Dubai, Conference Management Agency, Event organiser Dubai, Party Planning Dubai, Promotional Staff Dubai, Event Planning UAE, Event manager UAE, Event Services UAE, Corporate Events UAE, Party Event Planning UAE, Corporate Event Planning UAE, Exhibition Management UAE, Event Planning Service UAE, Event Management Agency UAE, Corporate Event Services UAE, Furniture Hire Dubai UAE, Conference Management Agency UAE, Event organiser Dubai UAE, Party Planning Dubai UAE, Promotional Staff Dubai UAE, Event Planning Dubai, Event manager Dubai, Event Services Dubai, Corporate Events Dubai, Party Event Planning Dubai, Corporate Event Planning Dubai, Corporate Event Management Dubai, Exhibition Management Dubai, Event Management Agency Dubai, Corporate Event Services Dubai, UAE event management Dubai, Furniture Hire Dubai " />

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="script/jqueryslidemenu.css" />

    {literal}
        <!--[if lte IE 7]>
        <style type="text/css">
            html .jqueryslidemenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/

            div#prevBtn {
            height:22px;
            float:left;
            width:15px;
            margin-top:-45px;
            padding:2px 0 0 10px;
            margin-left:320px;
            color:#b7b6a0;
        }
        div#nextBtn{ 
            height:22px;
            float:left;
            width:17px;
            padding:2px 0 0 8px;
            margin-top:-45px;
            margin-left:360px;
            color:#b7b6a0 !important;
        }   

        .staff-detail   {
            width:600px;
            padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
            color:#000000;
            line-height:16px;
            margin-top:-75px;
            float:left;
        }

        #image-form-container .forms span   {

            font-size:13px;

        }

        </style>
        <![endif]-->
    {/literal}

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="script/easySlider.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="script/easySlider.packed_news.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fadeSlideShow.js"></script>


    {literal}



        <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var imgArray = [ 'homeimg1', 'homeimg2', 'homeimg3', 'homeimg4', 'homeimg5' ];
    imgArray.sort(function () { return 0.5 - Math.random(); }); // shuffle the array
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $('#slideshow').prepend('<li><img src="img/'+ imgArray[i] +'.jpg" alt="" /></li>');
    }

    $('#slideshow').fadeSlideShow({
        width: 980,
        height: 386,
        speed: 600, //'slow'
        interval: 6000,
        PlayPauseElement: false,
        NextElement: false,
        PrevElement: false,
        addListToId: false
    });

    $("#slider").easySlider({
        speed: 800,
        auto: true,
        pause: 5000,
        continuous: true
    });
});
</script>



    {/literal}



    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="highslide/highslide.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="highslide/highslide.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/validation.js"></script>
    <script src="script/AC_RunActiveContent.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-57139118-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">


    <div id="top">

        <a href="/" title="Back to Homepage" id="logo"><img src="img/logo.gif" alt="Back to Homepage" /></a>

        <ul id="topMenu">
            <li><a href="/" class="act">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="main.php?pg=hwdi">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="event.php?arch=no&nid=4&fs=7" {if $article eq 'service'} class=act {/if}>Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="clients.php">Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="regional-coverage.php">Regional Coverage</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="cleaner"></div>
    </div>  




    <div id="content"><div class="content">

        <div id="homeImg">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <ul id="slideshow">
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="ourClients">
            <h3>Our Satisfied Clients</h3>

            <div id="sliderHolder"><div id="slider"><ul>    
                <li><a href="clients.php"><img src="img/clients/our-clients1.jpg" alt="Our Satisfied Clients" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.php"><img src="img/clients/our-clients2.jpg" alt="Our Satisfied Clients" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.php"><img src="img/clients/our-clients3.jpg" alt="Our Satisfied Clients" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.php"><img src="img/clients/our-clients4.jpg" alt="Our Satisfied Clients" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.php"><img src="img/clients/our-clients5.jpg" alt="Our Satisfied Clients" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.php"><img src="img/clients/our-clients6.jpg" alt="Our Satisfied Clients" /></a></li>
                <li><a href="clients.php"><img src="img/clients/our-clients7.jpg" alt="Our Satisfied Clients" /></a></li>
            </ul></div></div>

        </div>

        <div id="aboutCompany">
            <h3>{$title}</h3>

            <div class="l">{$CONTENT[0]|sslash}</div>

            <div class="r" style="margin-top:-30px;">{$CONTENT[1]|sslash}</div>

            <div class="cleaner"></div>
        </div>

    </div></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: can you paste your code here, in which you are getting error, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a JS, so you need to wrap that with `{literal}`.

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-57139118-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
{/literal}
```

Without using `{literal}` tag you need to write `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}`, instead of `{` and `}`.

Comment: I said whenever I enter just a space it gives me above fatal error... Js are already wrapped in literal

Comment: @user3354766: no, this script isn't wrapped in your updated question.